# Integrating Passport OAuth 2 strategy in Express for an AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I am looking to add OAuth 2 authentication to an angularjs application running off an Express 4.x web server.

I already have access to an API server that authenticates with OAuth 2 and have been supplied the client ID and secret, etc.

I have come across PassportJS and have seen the OAuth 2 strategy so this looks like exactly what I require.

From what I have read regarding OAuth 2, after a token request is made to the API provider, and that token is returned, the client needs to send this back as Bearer token in subsequent requests.

So my question is, does the Passport JS OAuth 2 strategy (passport-oauth2 plugin) prefix the returned token from the provider with 'Bearer'? I could not see anything in their docs, or when searching for 'Bearer' in the passport-oauth2 github source. So I am now wondering do I need to do something in addition to configuring this plugin?

I hope I have made some sort of sense with my question!

Thanks

Comment: Passport's documentation is the worst. That being said, here are some docs specifically related to the [oauth2](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2) and [http-bearer](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http-bearer) strategies that might shed a little light on your questions.

Comment: Thanks @Nocturno - tell me about it, I have been going round in circles reading what docs I can find!